# porting the method '__popcnt' to mingw

Tags: c++, mingw

In my Microsoft specific code I have something like this (which works and builds fine)

```
wfx->Channels = __popcnt(type);
```

Mingw has a problem recognizing `__popcnt` any suggestions on what I could use instead of that ?  This [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231.aspx) says its declared in `#include <intrin.h>` however adding that did not help. Any suggestions on what I could replace it with ? I do not have access to a Microsoft compiler and I cannot dig deeper into the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC has intrinsic functions for specialized processor instructions also, the matching ones are

```
__builtin_popcount
__builtin_popcountl
__builtin_popcountll
```

It doesn't look like any header file is needed.

They are most efficient when targeting a Nehalem or later processor, otherwise the compiler will have to generate a software implementation.

Comment: Compared trivial implementation, I just found that even at 9 bits, the LLVM intrinsic implemenation to be beneficial - 10% improvement in a sudoku solver (which uses "how many bits are set" to determine which is cells to fill in next) - using the popcnt instruction gives another 5% over the "use several instructions" intrinsic.